# Java security, possible values for method SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")

Tags: java, security, random, cryptography

Anyone knows what values this method accepts? What are the options available on a standard JDK 8 u40 ?

```
SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
```

Comment: It's best not to use any value and let the JVM select the best option depending on availability.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I considered that first, but then won't that leave me vulnerable for change later on? If the default change, I won't be able to compare hashes. Is that a correct assessment?

Comment: @momo: Compare *hashes*? You are confused.

Comment: @GregS How so? Don't I need to hash a provided password and compare it with a stored one?

Comment: @momo: That has nothing to do with SecureRandom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have look at the link 
[algorithms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecureRandom)

as mentioned in javadocs below given values are possible.

> NativePRNG
>
> NativePRNGBlocking
>
> NativePRNGNonBlocking
>
> PKCS11
>
> SHA1PRNG
>
> Windows-PRNG